# d3 brush and setting minimum tick marks with a time scale

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

**EDITED**

I am trying to set a minimum extent when 'brushing' the 'context' for a graph in focus.

Without worrying about setting a minimum I have successfully implemented a multi series chart with context and focus.

The problem is when the extent can be small enough that it will show hours on the dynamic focus chart when the brush is small enough.

My question is, is it possible to set a minimum tick mark or restrict the amount the brush can be reduced to in order to ensure ticks do not go down to hours, but are restricted to days?

The following code sets the minimum ticks but does so no matter how big the brush gets, thus showing way too may tick marks (days).

```
function brushed() {
            removeFixedLine();
            var newData = brush.empty() ? x2.domain() : brush.extent();
            x.domain(newData);

            // Redraw tooltip x-axis
            focus.selectAll(".dot")
                .attr("cx", function (d) { return x(d.date); } );

            // Redraw lines     
            focus.selectAll("path.datapath").attr("d", line);
            minExtent = d3.time.day(brush.extent()[1]) - d3.time.day(brush.extent()[0]);
            console.log(minExtent);
            var newXAxis = xAxis;

            if (minExtent > 8640000) {
                xAxis.ticks(d3.time.days, 1);
                focus.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
            }
            else {
                focus.select(".x.axis").call(newXAxis);
            }
}
```

*Note: this code has been edited and massaged so many times it may not make total sense, but the gist of what I wish to achieve should be there.*

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "minimum extent". Your code only seems to set the ticks?

Comment: So actually, What I need is for the tick marks and not the extent to have a minimum boundary of one day. I'll rephrase the question.

Comment: This is what `xAxis.ticks(d3.time.days, 1);` does, no?

Comment: But it seems to be doing it all the time, and the brush does not go back to the normal dynamic tick updating once larger than a day.

Comment: It sounds like you want your own [custom multi-scale format](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4149176) that uses days as the minimum boundary.

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for. I'm now convinced that D3 can do everything (apart from maybe wash my dishes). Thanks Lars.

Answer (score 2):

You can't force the brush to have a certain minimum extent when the user is manipulating it, but you can add a check in your `brushed` function to see if the extent is too small, and if so set it to your minimum value:

```
var minExtent = 8640000; 
    //minimum number of milliseconds to display in the focus chart

function brushed() {
        removeFixedLine();
        if ( brush.empty() ) {
            x.domain( x2.domain() ); //reset the domain (Note the typo fix!)
        } else {
            var newData = brush.extent();
            var width = newData[1] - newData[0]; 
                 //this assumes a single-direction brush,
                 //like in the original code

            if (width < minExtent) {
               var padding = ( minExtent - width )/2;
                   //amount to add onto each side of the extent
               newData[0] -= padding;
               newData[1] += padding;

               brush.extent(newData); 
                   //Update the extent value stored in the brush.

               brushGroup.call(brush); 
                   //Redraw the brush rectangles to match the modified extent.
                   //(Replace `brushGroup` with the d3 selection containing the 
                   //<g> element into which you originally drew the brush.)
            }

            x.domain(newData); 
                 //if width was greater than minExtent,
                 //this is just the extent from the brush
        }

        /* redraw the focus chart */

}
```

Note that there are three things that have to be done to apply your modified extent:

- set the extent on the brush object using [`brush.extent(values)`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Controls#wiki-brush_extent);
- redraw the SVG representation of the brush using [`brush(selection)`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Controls#wiki-_brush) or `selection.call(brush)` (which is the exact same thing, just written in a different way);
- use the modified extent as you normally would, to set the focus chart x-scale domain.

Comment: Apologies, although this may work (it's giving me an error at the moment) I think I actually need the tick marks to have a minimum of one day, but otherwise be dynamically set by the brush.

Comment: The intention is that if the brush-width is greater than the minimum, it gets used as is.  I'll correct one typo I see, if that doesn't fix the error let me know exactly what error you're getting and which line of code is triggering it.

Answer (score 0):

To set a monthly minimum limit:

```
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale).ticks(d3.timeMonth);
```

To set a daily minimum limit:

```
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale).ticks(d3.timeDay);
```